# Can we please default to the markdown view when reviewing suggested edits?

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, suggested-edits

I was reviewing the *Late answers* queue and noticed an answer with formatting problems. The user had posted some HTML code, but didn't format it at all, and therefore it was invisible:

> [image: Before edit]

So I fixed it:

> [image: After edit]

My edit is still being peer reviewed. It currently has 2 reject votes (both because "it deviates from the original intent") vs 1 approval vote. I guess the reviewers thought that I added code not originally present in the answer. They wouldn't have had this problem if they had switched to the "markdown" view, where the edit becomes pretty obvious:

[image: markdown]

I also added a comment to the suggested edit, with the following text: `fixed the code formatting, it was invisible otherwise`. However, it seems that I didn't explain myself clearly enough... *sigh*...

So, my question is: would it be possible to load by default the "markdown" view instead of the "rendered output", when reviewing suggested edits?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see two problems with this:

1. You can load the review queue to that view by default, but then the user can simply switch to another view for the next edit - your edit is up next and they *still* miss it because they're not in that view.
2. This is assuming that lot's of edits are of this nature and need to be seen in markdown view - which may not be the case and users may be annoyed if they have to keep changing the view every time they go into the edit queue because it defaulted to markdown

In summary, the problem isn't that the *view* isn't correct - it's that people reviewing your edit didn't read the comment you left.

Creating a default view isn't going to fix that problem unfortunately so I wouldn't see any real value in implementing this.

---

For example - on a generic review this view allows me to see straight away where the edits are and what needs my attention:

[image]

Whereas this takes a second or two longer to get my bearings before actually deciding on the content:

[image]

Comment: The first problem could easily be solved by forcing the same view each time you review a new item. Of course, this would be even more annoying if the users actually prefer the "rendered output" view. However... I fail to see how that view can be more useful when reviewing suggested edits. (On the other hand, I still don't have enough rep to access this queue, so... :)

Comment: `I fail to see how that view can be more useful when reviewing suggested edits` you're basing that view _solely_ on this type of edit though where html isn't visible. In most edits, the rendered output view is much more cleaner to look at and shows the edits in-line which can make it much faster to process rather than the markdown view

Comment: Looking at the screenshots you posted, I still can't see why the first view is better... they look pretty much the same in that example. But yeah, for bigger edits not involving code, it must be cleaner.